# Creating a directory containing today's date (PHP)

Tags: php

I'm pretty new at this forum, and don't know all functions, like how to paste code, but I'll try my best.

I've been using a PHP script for logging, and are now trying to create a log directory for each day.

The command I can't get to work is this one:

```
if (!file_exists('Logs/'.$todaydate'/')) { mkdir('Logs/'.$todaydate, 0777, true); }
```

I haven't fully comprehended how to incorporate data and text together.

my first try:

```
if (!file_exists('Logs/$todaydate/')) { mkdir('Logs/$todaydate', 0777, true); }
```

Just created a directory called `$todaydate`

The second try:

```
if (!file_exists('Logs/'.$todaydate'/')) { mkdir('Logs/'.$todaydate, 0777, true); }
```

Just created an syntax error..

Anybody got any idea?

Comment: You're missing a concatenction operator in `'Logs/'.$todaydate'/'` (i.e. `'Logs/'.$todaydate . '/'`

Comment: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first try failed because you can **only** use variables within strings when using **double quotes**. The correct way to do is is the following:

```
if (!file_exists("Logs/$todaydate/")) { mkdir("Logs/$todaydate", 0777, true); }
```

As for the second, as Rowland Shaw noted in his comment, you missed a concatenation operator.

```
if (!file_exists('Logs/'.$todaydate.'/')) { mkdir('Logs/'.$todaydate, 0777, true); }
```

Comment: So if I've understood this, when using single quote '  you need the concatenation (the dots)  on both sides of the variable, or else it won't "execute"  the variable, but if I put them inside a double quote " , you can mix text and variables.... Or am I way of?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Read: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Great, now I just wrote $myFile = "$dir/$ip.access.log"; and it worked great, and I have struggled with understanding that, and now I just understand, thx